# linked list delete function

Tags: c

The following code snippet is not working right.

```
void deleteNode(list **start, int pos) {
    int currentPosition=0;
    list *currentNode;
    list *nodToDelete;

    currentNode = *start;
    if (currentNode == NULL) {
        printf("Empty List\n");
    } else if (pos == 0 ) {
        nodToDelete = *start;
        *start = nodToDelete->next;
        free(nodToDelete);
    } else {
        while (currentNode->next != NULL) {
            if (currentPosition >= pos -1) {
                break;
            }
            currentPosition++;
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
        }
        if (currentPosition < pos -1 || currentNode->next == NULL) {
            printf("No node at given position exists\n");
        } else {
            nodToDelete = currentNode->next;
            currentNode = nodToDelete->next;
            free(nodToDelete);
            nodToDelete = NULL;
        }
    }
}

void displayList(list *node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        printf("Empty List");
    }

    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%d\t", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    list *start, *node;
    start = NULL;

    insertNode(&start, 2);
    insertNode(&start, 3);
    insertNode(&start, 4);
    insertNode(&start, 1);
    insertNode(&start, 5);

    deleteNode(&start, 3);

    displayList(start);
}
```

When executed the output is

> Before Deletion  2    3   4   1   5
>   After Deletion   2    3   4   0   5

It is supposed to delete 1 but it is inserting 0 at its place.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; please show the definition of `list`.

Comment: Shouldn't currentNode = nodToDelete->next be currentNode->next = nodToDelete->next;

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that might work -- 
Replace

```
currentNode = nodToDelete->next;
```

with

```
currentNode->next = nodToDelete->next;
```

You basically need the node before the nodetodelete to have its next to point to the node that nodetodelete used to point to

Answer (score 1):

Once you've found the node you want to take out of the list, you need to actually take it out. =)

...

```
nodToDelete = currentNode->next;
currentNode->next = nodToDelete->next;
free(nodToDelete);
```

...

Comment: thanks for the solution 
so ultimately it turned out to be a 0 level bug, which i could not figure out

Answer (score 1):

Besides the problem with `currentNode->next = nodToDelete->next;` and negative positions you are mixing your ui and your logic.  As much as possible you should separate the two.

Sending something to the ui is a way of reporting progress; whether the ui is a command line, a browser or a speaker. Within deleteNode, an empty list or a position that is out of bounds, is not progress. Sequentially both are the same as success - you are done.  If you want failure to be to be reported, that should be done where it can lead to a separate sequence...i.e the caller.  Also, by mixing in ui, you introduce an unnecessary dependency and failure (what if there's a bug in printf, YOUR function will crash when it doesn't doesn't have to).  If you're function returns a defined result, the caller can decide if/how to report that result, including success (your function currently doesn't do so, and the caller has no way telling the difference between sucess or failure).